# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: spring-jdbc

I got this exception while connecting to spring JDBC. I am using Oracle 11 XE.

> Jan 06, 2015 2:49:11 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
>           INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@5d099f62: startup date [Tue Jan 06 14:49:11 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
>           Jan 06, 2015 2:49:12 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
>           INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/jdbc/commons/application-context.xml]
>           Jan 06, 2015 2:49:12 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
>           INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6b71769e: defining beans [dataSource,jdbcTemplate,empdao]; root of factory hierarchy
>           Jan 06, 2015 2:49:12 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
>           INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
>           Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:573)
>               at com.jdbc.dao.EmployeeDao.getEmployeesByName(EmployeeDao.java:84)
>               at com.jdbc.test.JdbcTemplateTest.main(JdbcTemplateTest.java:21)
>           Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:458)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:236)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
>               at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>               at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
>               at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
>               ... 3 more
>           Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
>               at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:392)
>               at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:434)
>               at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:687)
>               at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:363)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102)
>               at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320)
>               ... 15 more
>           Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>               at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
>               at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
>               at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>               at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>               at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>               at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>               at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>               at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>               at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:150)
>               at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
>               at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:370)
>               ... 20 more

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I am using the PostGres SQL jar 10.0 and I had updated it to recent jar and tried and it didn't worked out. The issue got resolved after I took back up of the DB instead of creating the new DB. This was some DB issues. Changed the configuration of drive to postgres driver.

Comment: How did you get an Oracle error message from a PostGres JAR file?

Comment: in the configuration files we have given oracle driver instead of postgres driver